# RSpec less strict equality expectation for test

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing, rspec

I have the following test:

```
it "can add an item" do
    item = Item.new("car", 10000.00)
    expect(@manager.add_item("car", 10000.00)).to eq(item)
end
```

Item's initialize looks like (class has attr_accessor for, type, price, and is_sold):

```
  def initialize(type, price)
    @type = type
    @price = price
    @is_sold = false
    @@items << self
  end
```

Manager's add item looks like:

```
  def add_item(type, price)
    Item.new(type, price)
  end
```

This test is currently failing because the two items have different object ids, although their attributes are identical. Item's initialize method takes a type, and a price. I only want to check for equality on those features...  Is there a way to test strictly for attribute equality?

I have tried should be, should eq, to be, and eql? with no luck.

Comment: Please post the entire code for the `Item` class. In the code you've posted `type` and `price` are assigned to instance variables and RSpec (or any code outside the instance) has no way to access or compare those values. Does the class have e.g. `attr_reader` so other code can access them?

Comment: `item` and `@manager.add_item("car", 10000.00))` will be two different instances of the same class `Item`. If you want to test if the attributes are the same, let `i0 = Item.new("car", 10000.00); i2 = Item.new("car", 10000.00)`, then test `i0.type == i1.type`, etc.,

Comment: @Jordan, yes theres an attr_accessor on type and price, will update code to reflect that

Comment: And yes @CarySwoveland, that's true. But they have matching name and type. That's what I am trying to compare in this unit test.

Comment: @Jordan, I'm not sure that's needed, as long as we know there are read accessors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your class has a public interface for reading those attributes (e.g. `attr_reader :type, :price`), then the most sensible way is probably to implement a `==` method:

```
class Item
  # ...

  def ==(other)
    self.type == other.type &&
      self.price == other.price
  end
end
```

This allows any two Items to be compared using `==`, and so RSpec's `eq` method will work as expected.

If you don't want your class to have an equality method, your best bet is probably to check each attribute individually:

```
it "can add an item" do
  expected = Item.new("car", 10000.00)
  actual = @manager.add_item("car", 10000.00)

  expect(actual.type).to eq(expected.type)
  expect(actual.price).to eq(expected.price)
end
```

But as you can probably tell this may become a maintainability challenge as you add features to Item.

Comment: Don't you then have to test `Item#==`?

Comment: Yes, you should have specs for that method as well.

Comment: both of these solutions work, but I think your first suggestion is better than your second for longevity's sake... say another dev changes Item's intialize in the future, the test will still pass. thanks.

Comment: 'gator, I agree, but Jordan's addition is a hair's breathe different than what I suggested.

Comment: For what it's worth, @CarySwoveland, I added the second part of my answer before I saw your answer.

Comment: I'm not surprised. It happens to me all the time. In fact, I make it a point not to look at other answers until I'm ready to post.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

```
it "can add an item" do
  item0 = Item.new("car", 10000.00)
  item1 = @manager.add_item("car", 10000.00)
  expect(item0.name==item1.name && item0.type==item1.type)
end
```